# Pandas with Snowflake is not working >> exit code 139

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pyarrow

I am installing Snowflake connector using the following code

```
pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python
pip install snowflake-connector-python[pandas]
```

Everything installs as expected. The problem occurs when I  import Snowflake.

```
import snowflake.connector as sf
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I get the above error. If I don't run the second pip install command I can import snowflake.connector. I've narrowed the issue down to pyarrow which is a requirement for using Pandas with Snowflake and comes  with the second pip install command.

```
import pyarrow as pa
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this error?

Comment: Hmmm...there is not a lot to go on unfortunately.  Importing pyarrow definitely should not raise SIGSEGV.  If you are on Linux you could try running the import with gdb.  First run `gdb --args python -c "import pyarrow"` and then type `run` and you should get a stack trace.

Comment: I am on a mac. That GDB command doesn't work.

Comment: I use snowflake in a mac too. You can try installing Anaconda. Then, create an environment and install all the libraries you need in the GUI. When I install my dependencies in that way, I can be sure that the dependencies will get the correct versions.